# Does Spark Graphx have visualization like Gephi

Tags: apache-spark, graph, spark-graphx

I am new to graph world. I have been assigned to work on graph processing. Now I know Apache Spark, so thought of using it Graphx to process large graph. Then I came across Gephi provides nice GUI to manipulate graphs.

Does Graphx have such tools or it is mainly parallel graph processing library. Can I import json graph data came from Gephi into graphx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to that you can as well try Graphlab
https://dato.com/products/create/open_source.html

It directly support Spark RDD 
https://dato.com/learn/userguide/data_formats_and_sources/spark_integration.html

Not much work required after that

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
import graphlab as gl

sc = SparkContext('yarn-client')

t = sc.textFile("hdfs://some/large/file")
sf = gl.SFrame.from_rdd(t)

# do stuff...

out_rdd = sf.to_rdd(sc)
```

Answer (score 0):

No, Apache Spark Graphx have no visualization, it's just a processing engine but you can import data from gephi to graphx using Gephi's API.